# Is it possible for a picture box to detect colour in another picture box and avoid it?

Tags: vb.net

I am currently attempting to make a visual route planner interface for a local town.
The GUI is a map lacking in detail simply showing a green background with grey lines for the roads.
Is it possible for another picture box representing a vehicle to avoid and be unable to access the green coloured areas of the Map Picture box?

How can I make the car picture box follow certain routes along the map picture box that can be worked out through calculations?

Comment: Are you planning on making a pathfinding algorithm based on images? Roads are usually organized into networks. I hope you're working with the networks and not the rasters.

Comment: I am planning on finding the fastest route yes, but also allowing the user to choose which roads can be avoided, How can I organise them into networks?

Comment: There is a whole field of study about GIS and another one about pathfinding. A not-too-complicated-yet-powerful way to achieve what you want would to create a network of nodes with coordinated and vertex to connect them, and then apply an A* algorithm to it. How good are you with programming?

Comment: I would like to say I am a good coder when it comes to console, I am currently attempting to convert to windows forms, I should be able to program an algorithm like dijkstras, how would I make nodes on the map and ensure the car picture box can go around curves etc to reach the node?

Comment: Where are your maps from, do you create them yourself or are them from an outside source?

Comment: I have made a map using mspaint which is simply a green area with grey lines representing roads.

Comment: Good then, it'll be waaay easier this way. My time is limited right now, so I'll start writing an answer that I'll enrich as you progress.

Comment: Thank you very much, one way I have thought of using other transparent picture boxes but this became a problem on roads that were not straight.

Comment: Unless you want to "animate" the movements, the shapes of the roads won't slow you down. This is going to be fun.

Answer (score 0):

We'll do this in a couple steps:

1. Build the map from the data.
2. Implement a flexible pathfinding algorithm.
3. Draw a human-friendly version of the map.
4. Wrap up with user interactions.

I'll enrich this answer as you progress so it stays relevant.

---

### 1

First thing, we'll manipulate data. A road map is basically a network of points (or nodes) linked by lines (which I'll call vertex).

The points have coordinates (so we can draw them later), and sometimes other values, like a name. They are every start and end of a road, and sometimes in-between. To keep things simple, the user will only be able to start and end on points.

Vertex have length and sometimes stuff like "difficulty", "max speed", etc. These stats will determinate which road is the most optimized for the user's trip. We can also make sure that the algorithm doesn't consider a vertex when the user doesn't want to go this way, or force him to go through a specific vertex if we choose so.

You'll find that I included a sample map by setting it up in the map's constructor. I included approximative coordinates and distances. You can change it any way you like. Here what the data represents:

[image: Sample map]

---

### 2

I'm using the A* (read `A STAR`) algorithm here. You mentioned Dijkstra's algorithm sooner, which is nice, but for this purpose I'll stick to A*.

There are differences between these two methods. If you wikipedia them, you'll find these two images which, I think, show really well the main difference between the two:

Dijkstra's algorithm:

[image: Dijkstra's algorithm]

A* algorithm:

[image: A* algorithm]

As you can see by yourself, both algorithm are doing a fine job.

I commented the code, but You'll probably have a ton of questions about all these things. I'll hang around to answer them.

To manipulate this algorithm, you have to know this:

- the `difficulty` value of a vertex makes it seem longer to the algorithm. It's not necessary (which is why I put it to 1 everywhere), but if you want to compare a mountain road to a speedway or a road with a 30 km/h speed limit to another one where you can speed at 100 km/h, you can tweak this value.
- the x and y coordinates of the nodes aren't very important in themselves, but the A* algorithm uses them to get this "I'm going toward my goal" effect you just saw in the image. Approximatives values are fine, as long as there are values that make some sense in there. You could calculate the H value otherwise, but as this is cartography I though it made sense.
- a vertex MUST ALWAYS be connected to a starting point and an end point. Which is which have no meaning, as long as there are two of them (or the same point twice, but that would lead to the place where it started without any gain whatsoever).
- a point may have any number of vertex.
- you could make some points "impossible to pass", but I didn't code it that way. You can pump up the difficulty to an insane amount to get a somewhat similar result, except that if there are no other way the algorithm will eventually use the difficult path anyway.
- if the end node has no connection to the network of the starting node, the algorithm will try everything then abandon and let you know that there is no path to the end point.
- use the `TestMyMap()` sub to try some pathfinding. Calculate it by yourself to compare. Change the end point and the starting point for something else. Go wild!

---

### The Code

```
#Region " Mapping "
    Public Class MapPoint
        Private _vertexList As New List(Of MapVertex) 'one point can have as many "roads" as you want
        Private _xCoord As Decimal 'for now the coordinates are meaningless, but at some point we might want to use them to actually paint the map
        Private _yCoord As Decimal
        Private _name As String 'just a useful label
        Public Parent As MapVertex = Nothing 'useful for backtracking at the end (and get an itinary)

        'f is the total "cost" of the the node being analyzed (f = g + h) while doing pathfinding
        'g is the distance between the node being analyzed and the starting point while doing pathfinding
        'those values serve no other purpose
        'h is the estimated minimal distance between the two points while doing pathfinding
        'in the Sub 'CalculateH' I'm using the points coordinates and simple trigonometry to estimate h
        'technically you can skip the square root part, but I decided against it. There are no dealmaking advantages to my decision.
        'it's better to underestimate the minimal distance, that's why a theoretical straight line is a good choice
        Public f As Decimal = 0
        Public g As Decimal = 0
        Public h As Decimal = 0

        Public ReadOnly Property VertexList As List(Of MapVertex)
            Get
                Return _vertexList
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property X As Decimal
            Get
                Return _xCoord
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Y As Decimal
            Get
                Return _yCoord
            End Get
        End Property

        Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
            Get
                Return _name
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(name As String, xx As Decimal, yy As Decimal, ParamArray vertex() As MapVertex)
            _name = name
            _xCoord = xx
            _yCoord = yy
            For Each v As MapVertex In vertex
                _vertexList.Add(v)
            Next
        End Sub

        Public Sub AddVertex(vertex As MapVertex)
            _vertexList.Add(vertex)
        End Sub

        Public Sub CalculateH(startingPoint As MapPoint, endPoint As MapPoint)
            h = Convert.ToDecimal(Math.Sqrt(Math.Pow((startingPoint.X - endPoint.X), 2) + Math.Pow((startingPoint.Y - endPoint.Y), 2)))
        End Sub

        Public Sub UpdateFandG(currentNodeG As Decimal, distance As Decimal)
            g = currentNodeG + distance
            f = g + h
        End Sub

        Public Sub ResetPathfindingValues()
            f = 0
            g = 0
            h = 0
            Parent = Nothing

            For Each v As MapVertex In _vertexList
                v.ResetPathfindingValues()
            Next
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class MapVertex
        Private _name As String 'just a useful label
        Private _length As Decimal 'length of the road. If you have straight roads we can use simple math to get the distances, but curvy roads have their own length, and I'll assume that your roads will be anything
        Private _difficulty As Decimal 'if you want to make some roads faster than others, we can use a variable like this one. It could be something else, like "maxSpeed", but for a prototype "difficulty" will do fine
        'I suggest making the difficulty a multiplier. It'll be easier to use that way (so a road twice faster would be a '0.5' and a road twice harder to use would be a '2.0')
        Public Parent As MapPoint = Nothing 'useful for backtracking at the end (and get an itinary)

        'start and end has no meaning here, as both are end points for the line. The important part is that they refer to existing points
        'a vertex must ALWAYS be linked to two points (or it makes no sense, you cannot have a line with only one end unless you go full moebius and we're not using enough dimensions for this to make sense
        'if you feel like it, you can have a vertex looping from one point and going back to it, but it'll serve no purpose and will never be actually used except by the pathfinding algorithm (which will note it as a bad move every time)
        Private _startPoint As MapPoint
        Private _endPoint As MapPoint

        Public ReadOnly Property Name As String
            Get
                Return _name
            End Get
        End Property

        'you can play around with difficulty if you like, it'll change which path the algorithm thinks is the better
        Public ReadOnly Property AdjustedLength As Decimal
            Get
                Return _length * _difficulty
            End Get
        End Property

        Public Sub New(name As String, startPoint As MapPoint, endPoint As MapPoint, length As Decimal, difficulty As Decimal)
            _name = name
            _startPoint = startPoint
            _endPoint = endPoint
            _length = length
            _difficulty = difficulty

            'automatically adding this vertex to it's points on creation:
            _startPoint.AddVertex(Me)
            _endPoint.AddVertex(Me)
        End Sub

        'this function is so we can get the "other side" of a path from it's start
        Public Function GetOtherNode(currentNode As MapPoint) As MapPoint
            If _startPoint Is currentNode Then
                Return _endPoint
            Else
                Return _startPoint
            End If
        End Function

        Public Sub ResetPathfindingValues()
            Parent = Nothing
        End Sub
    End Class

    Public Class Map
        'the Map object is a collection of points.
        'those points are linked by vertex
        'it could be different depending on what's your purpose

        Private _points As New List(Of MapPoint)

        Public Function GetPoint(name As String) As MapPoint
            For Each p As MapPoint In _points
                If p.Name = name Then
                    Return p
                End If
            Next

            Return Nothing
        End Function

        Public Sub New()
            'You can use this part to build a simple map with a handful of points. For the demonstration that's how we'll work, but later on you can design a mean to load maps from a specific source if you want
            'Here's one I threw on the screen at random. If you have one you like better, send me a pastebin and I'll use it instead

            'First I create the points:
            Dim oldBarn As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Old Barn", 0, 0)
            Dim home As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Home", 0, 12)
            Dim forest As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Forest", 0, 21)
            Dim creepyDeadEnd As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Creepy Dead End", 0, 26)
            Dim groceries As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Groceries", 11, 8)
            Dim girlfriendsPlace As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Girlfriend's Place", 20, 8)
            Dim friendsHome As MapPoint = New MapPoint("Friend's Home", 5, 13)
            Dim bar As MapPoint = New MapPoint("The Foo's Bar", 32, 14)   'hehehe

            'Second I create the roads between those points (as long as 2 points exist I could create the road, I just decided I would be systematic)
            Dim smallRoad As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Small Road", oldBarn, home, 12, 1)
            Dim oakStreet As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Oak Street", home, forest, 9, 1)
            Dim pathway As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Pathway", forest, creepyDeadEnd, 5, 1)
            Dim oldRoad As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Old Road", oldBarn, friendsHome, 17, 1)
            Dim arlingtonStreet As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Arlington Street", home, groceries, 7, 1)
            Dim fourthStreet As MapVertex = New MapVertex("4th Street", home, girlfriendsPlace, 12, 1)
            Dim placeLittlefinger As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Place Littlefinger", groceries, girlfriendsPlace, 9, 1)
            Dim cedarCreek As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Cedar Creek", forest, bar, 19, 1)
            Dim alley As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Alley", friendsHome, groceries, 7, 1)
            Dim mainStreet As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Main Street", groceries, bar, 22, 1)
            Dim durnhamRoad As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Durnham Road", friendsHome, bar, 27, 1)
            Dim secretRoad As MapVertex = New MapVertex("Secret Road", oldBarn, bar, 61, 1)

            'Adding the points to the Map
            _points.AddRange({oldBarn, home, forest, creepyDeadEnd, groceries, girlfriendsPlace, friendsHome, bar})
        End Sub

        'This is an implementation of the A* algorithm, which is a very popular pathfinding algorithm for simple grids/node networks
        'You could use Dijkstra's algorithm if you like it better or are a Sapkowsky's fan, but I think A* will do a great job here
        Public Function FindTheShortestPath(startingPoint As MapPoint, endPoint As MapPoint) As String
            Dim openList As New List(Of MapPoint)   'nodes that are going to be analyzed soon
            Dim closedList As New List(Of MapPoint) 'nodes that have been analyzed

            'we always start the analysis... from the starting point of course!
            openList.Add(startingPoint)
            startingPoint.CalculateH(startingPoint, endPoint)

            'as long as we haven't found the path to the end point, the algorithm will continue looking
            'there are 2 ways to exit this function:
            ' #1 is finding the endPoint
            ' #2 is having nowhere left to go and still not finding the end point (which means that it's impossible)
            While (openList.Count > 0)
                'look for the lowest f in the openList
                'this is our current node for the analysis
                Dim currentNode As MapPoint = Nothing
                For Each p As MapPoint In openList
                    If currentNode Is Nothing OrElse p.f < currentNode.f Then
                        currentNode = p
                    End If
                Next

                'remove the currentNode from the open list (it's being analyzed) and add to the closedList (no need to come back)
                openList.Remove(currentNode)
                closedList.Add(currentNode)

                'check if we've reached the end node
                If currentNode Is endPoint Then
                    'yay!
                    'now let's backtrack to get an itinary:

                    Dim path As String = BackTrack(endPoint)
                    ResetAllPathfindingVariables()
                    Return path
                End If

                'finding which nodes are connected to the Current node
                'then analyzing it
                For Each vertex As MapVertex In currentNode.VertexList
                    Dim nextNode As MapPoint = vertex.GetOtherNode(currentNode)

                    'only work on a node if it's out of the closedList
                    If Not closedList.Contains(nextNode) Then
                        'I'm tracking parents to make an itinary when this is finished
                        nextNode.CalculateH(currentNode, endPoint)
                        nextNode.UpdateFandG(currentNode.g, vertex.AdjustedLength)

                        'if it's not yet on the openList, now's time to add it there!
                        '(I know that a negative check with a 'Else' clause is stupid, but it's easier to read in this context)
                        If Not openList.Contains(nextNode) Then
                            openList.Add(nextNode)
                            nextNode.UpdateFandG(currentNode.g, vertex.AdjustedLength)
                            nextNode.Parent = vertex
                            vertex.Parent = currentNode
                        Else
                            'if this is a known node but we found a faster path to reach it, update it's parent
                            If currentNode.g + vertex.AdjustedLength < nextNode.g Then
                                nextNode.UpdateFandG(currentNode.g, vertex.AdjustedLength)
                                nextNode.Parent = vertex
                                vertex.Parent = currentNode
                            End If
                        End If
                    End If
                Next
            End While

            ResetAllPathfindingVariables()
            Return "No path was found."
        End Function

        Private Sub ResetAllPathfindingVariables()
            For Each p As MapPoint In _points
                p.ResetPathfindingValues()
            Next
        End Sub

        'recursive function to show the path found by the algorithm
        Private Function BackTrack(location As Object, Optional path As String = "") As String
            If path <> "" Then path = " => " & path

            Select Case True
                Case TypeOf location Is MapPoint
                    Dim currentPoint As MapPoint = DirectCast(location, MapPoint)
                    path = currentPoint.Name & path
                    If currentPoint.Parent Is Nothing Then
                        Return path
                    Else
                        Return BackTrack(currentPoint.Parent, path)
                    End If

                Case TypeOf location Is MapVertex
                    Dim currentVertex As MapVertex = DirectCast(location, MapVertex)
                    path = currentVertex.Name & path
                    If currentVertex.Parent Is Nothing Then
                        Return path
                    Else
                        Return BackTrack(currentVertex.Parent, path)
                    End If
            End Select

            Return ""
        End Function
    End Class

    Private Sub TestMyMap()
        _map = New Map()

        Dim path As String = _map.FindTheShortestPath(_map.GetPoint("Home"), _map.GetPoint("The Foo's Bar"))
        Console.WriteLine(path)
    End Sub
#End Region
```

Of course I'll be there to help you understand this part. It's heavy, I know. It's still a lot of fun, especially once it's finished and you get to use it!

Comment: Thank you very much I will trouble shoot with this.

Comment: Would you be able to comment on the code so I can know what each part does so I can tweak with it?

Comment: Don't worry, this is just a mockup that will probably change over time until you have a working example. I added some comments to make things clear enough for you to experiment with it a little bit.

Comment: @DanielJones I edited the answer with more code and a pathfinding algorithm. You will probably have questions (I would be surprised if you don't). Don't hesitate to reach out.

Comment: How do I implement the code and change it to correspond with my map?

Comment: First step would be to copy this code into a project and make it work. Test it, play with it until you understand how to use it. Then, second step is to design your own map as a network of nodes and vertex, and use it instead of the mockup I used. The "map" was designed in the `Map` object's constructor. I commented it, but in short you create the nodes first, then the vertex (to which you "give" the corresponding nodes when you initialize them). You can copy the code in a windows form and set up a button to fire up `TestMyMap()`. That's what I did to test it in fact.

Comment: Would you be able to make code without the algorithm? Simply just the placing of the points and declaring which other roads they can travel to?

Comment: Yes, that is possible. Sorry I just realized that when you say "console" you probably don't mean "game console". I don't know why I didn't connect the dots at first. Are you a student or are you learning on your own? Now, do you want a "list of all the reachable places"? Since we have the distances, we can modify the algorithm to give directions to every one of these places, with the distance for each trip. If that's something that you're after.

Comment: I am a student, I am looking to learn how to do most of this on my own, All I am looking for is the declaration of certain locations and the linking of them, declaring which ones can travel to which.